# How can I calculate average of 3 fields with overrides?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, I have no experience with equations in jQuery, so please forgive me for not coming at this with 'where I am up to'. I'd be happy with just some pointers or starting points, if need be.

I need to create a form that has three number input fields. The user enters the 3 figures and the code provides the average of the three.

Then tick boxes calculate divide that averaged amount by x, y, z.

I'm not even sure where to begin with this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Break the problem up into chunks. Write one function that takes 3 numbers and does the math, then returns the result. Test that with some data sets from the console in your browser. Make sure whatever values you give it returns the correct result. After that, work on making the form read data from the input boxes and then pass the data to your function. Think separation of concerns. Good luck!

Comment: The first step is to actually write the HTML; add a form, add the input fields ... then, add a [change handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on each input field ... then, see how far you can get before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are tag specific, then

```
 var sum = 0;

 $("form > input").each(function() {

     sum += $(this).val();

 });

 sum = sum/3;
```

Comment: I don't think he was looking for an *exact* answer but just some help getting started. We should encourage people who are trying to learn and not just be told the answer. :)

Comment: Sure James Mortensen, will follow it from now on.

Comment: No probs guys, thanks for the info and sorry again for asking early in the piece.